# How to show the current branch only on status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

What settings do I need to set to see only the current branch I am working on?  Currently I am seeing this:

[image]

I do not want to see "[multiple]" ... just the current branch I am working on.  Can this be turned off?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by not having projects from multiple repositories in your solution. Do you use submodules?

Comment: @CodeCaster - Not quite sure what you mean by submodules... I should still be able to see only the current branch I am working on.  This should be configurable.  Originally it only showed the current branch regardless of whether I had multiple repo's in my solution.

Comment: But that makes no sense. Which repo should it show when you're working on multiple? That where the .sln is in?

Comment: I am not working on multiple... i just happen to reference another project. Worse come to worse... I should be able to disable this off the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

The repository selection button shows "2 Repositories", meaning you have a solution open in which projects from multiple repositories are loaded.

The "[multiple]" button indicates that those repositories have different branches checked out.

I don't know if you can disable this behavior. If it would show one repository and one branch, which would that be?

Comment: Yep I see that, it would be nice if I could set the repo that I want to be the active repo... this would then only show the branch I am working on for that repo.  Sounds like I'm stuck with this.  I looked into Tools->Options and could not find anything to alter this behavior so...  just very annoying... .